# JVM_Bind error when client socket is closed by the server and then new socket opened by the client on the same port

Tags: java, windows, sockets, tcp

This problem is intermittent, occurring every few hours on a process that runs every 30 seconds and performs the following network communication:

- There is a server on a remote machine listening
- The client connects to this machine and tells the server to connect back to it
- The **server** closes the socket and reconnects to the client
- When the socket closes on the client side, the client immediately starts listening on the same port

The JVM_Bind error happens on the client when it tries to start listening on the same port, even though it only tries to do this after the original socket is closed. Adding a slight delay of 100 milliseconds between the socket closing and opening a new socket prevents the JVM_Bind error.

What tools can I use to debug this scenario? Running continuous netstat has not shown anything interfering with the port.

Even though it's a kind of bad idea to start a new socket listening on the same port, why would this error occur intermittently?

**EDIT :** Some additional information. The server connects back to the client from an ephemeral port on the server. The Client's old socket would go straight into CLOSED and should be able to be re-opened. Wouldn't the likely cause be something happening on the OS, JVM or hardware?

Comment: `socket.setReuseAddress(true);` Have you tried this already?

Comment: *Why* does the server connect back to the client, when it already has an inbound connection to the client? This is wasteful, and it is a contributing cause to this problem. Just don't do it. Use the connection the client established.

Comment: EJP, it does this as part of a security mechanism. The server will only connect back to a list of trusted IP addresses.

Comment: @Jim If the inbound connection isn't already from a trusted address it should be closed. There is no need for a second reverse connection.

Comment: @EJP Chasing up on this 4 year old issue? :) I agree that the procedure doesn't make much sense but in this case we're dealing with a legacy protocol that we have to support. This question isn't asking for a better solution, it's about debugging the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with this issue we eventually ran Wireshark and Procmon to monitor the TCP connections and packets. Procmon is a really great tool for debugging problems on Windows and can be configured to show when TCP connections are created and dropped. Wireshark shows the actual packet data going across the line. This output showed that things were proceeding as they should have when the JVM_Bind error occurs. There was no material difference in the logs between when it worked and when it failed.

This pointed the blame at the system. I thought about system settings and then turned my attention to the possibility of a driver problem. Updated the network adapter drivers and the problem has gone away.

Moral of the story is to debug network problems with Wireshark and Procmon, it turned this problem into an analysable one.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29)

When a TCP connection is closed the connection may remain in a timeout state for a period of time after the connection is closed (typically known as the TIME_WAIT state or 2MSL wait state). For applications using a well known socket address or port it may not be possible to bind a socket to the required SocketAddress if there is a connection in the timeout state involving the socket address or port.

Why it would enter this state is detailed [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html).

[image: This is how it enters the TIME_WAIT state]

Now this does not occur everytime you disconnect the socket, which is why probably why the problem is intermittent.

**Enabling SO_REUSEADDR prior to binding the socket using bind(SocketAddress) allows the socket to be bound even though a previous connection is in a timeout state.**

```
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

Comment: DarkXphenomenon, the port is not a well known port (0 to 1023). It is in the 4000s on the client side. So I don't think this is applicable.

Comment: This is applicable to TCP connections in general. It is independent of the port.

Comment: The port on the Client actually goes immediately into a CLOSED state when the remote end disconnects. The Server would go into TIME_WAIT. Even if it was going into TIME_WAIT, it doesn't account for why a 100ms delay would solve the Client's socket-binding problem.

Comment: Did you try removing the delay and adding socket.setReuseAddress(true);. What result did you get then?

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. Only happens sporadically though, very annoying to try and debug.